# Change namespace to project

Tags: qooxdoo

when I created my project I typed its name wrong and I started to programming because still I'm learning, now I have many classes in many files and growing and I'd like to rename it, it is possible ? let's say from : ame_testqooxdooini1 to wrs
Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, it is possible but probably you have to do this by hand. I'm not aware of any automated way using the create-application.py or something similar

Comment: Cool !!! can you please give any hints, besides renaming source folder and paths what else I have to do ? Thanks Stelios

Answer (score 2):

close your editor, open a shell and then do this:

```
OLD=badname
NEW=goodname
cd source/class
mv $OLD $NEW
find $NEW -name '*.js' -print0 | \
   xargs -0 perl -i~ -p -e "s/${OLD}\./${NEW}./g"
```

Comment: Tobi, is this for Windows or linux ? in my case I use windows.

Comment: This is for linux ... if you are stuck with windows you can also get a copy of the free atom text editor ... it has a nice function todo search and replace in a project.

Comment: I think my text editor ( EditPlus ) does the same, so, if I rename project's folder and replace classe's path to the new one, and rebuild source that could be enougth ? Thank you very much for your assistance